# React: programmatically creating a grid

Tags: reactjs

Completely new to React.
In the react tic-tac-toe tutorial, they make a 3x3 hard coded grid with this code:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="board-row">
                {this.renderSquare(0)}
                {this.renderSquare(1)}
                {this.renderSquare(2)}
            </div>
            <div className="board-row">
                {this.renderSquare(3)}
                {this.renderSquare(4)}
                {this.renderSquare(5)}
            </div>
            <div className="board-row">
                {this.renderSquare(6)}
                {this.renderSquare(7)}
                {this.renderSquare(8)}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Is it possible to create a grid based on a gridSize passed into props such that the entire code in render() is a loop?
Something like:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      for (let row=0; row<props.gridSize; row++) {
        <BoardRow rowIndex=row cols=gridSize> (how to pass two parameters to BoardRow?)
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a couple of `Array.from`s to create new arrays from a given length, you can multiply the outer index (0 to 2) by 3 and add it to the inner index (0 to 2).

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>{
      Array.from({ length: 3 }, (_, i) => (
        <div className="board-row">{
          Array.from({ length: 3 }, (_, j) => (
            this.renderSquare((i * 3) + j)
          ))
        }</div>
      ))
    }</div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. I was trying to create a BoardRow function or class and pass in parameters.

Comment: one warning i'm now getting is 'Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.' in the renderSquare method, i tried adding a 'key={i.toString()}' to see if that helped, but i still get the warning.